# Android Shortcut app

Tags: java, android

I would like to create shortcut on home screen i used this code below :

```
Intent shortcut = new ntent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

ApplicationInfo appInfo = getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo();

shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Appname");

shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false); 

ComponentName component = new ComponentName(appInfo.packageName,"SplashScreenActivity.this");

shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setComponent(component));

Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), appInfo.icon);

shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(shortcut);
```

And this one :

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Appname");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

When i click on the shortcut i got toast app isn't install.
i have added this permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
```

and i tried many other solutions but always the same problem.